# Docker Web server on a secondary local IP

Tags: docker, localhost

I have a Linux server running Ubuntu with a web server on my local IP (port 80)

and I would like to set up a secondary local IP with a Docker web server on port 80.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, set the IP when specifying the exposed ports:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:<container-port> ...
docker run -p 127.0.0.2:80:<container-port> ...
```

Comment: Thanks but I mean with local IPs something like 192.168.178.XX
so I need to tell my DHCP server that I want a new IP right?

Comment: DHCP servers typically offer a single IP address for each MAC address, so that's not likely to work unless you have two network interfaces. What you could do is add a virtual interface and assign it a static IP address which is outside the DHCP range but hopefully within your subnet.